# Randomly Select from Array in PERL / AGI

Tags: perl, agi

I have a PERL script (not sure) that generates a random number (caller ID) for Asterisk / GoAutodial CRM.

The generated number begins by "+4124*******" and a random number for the rest of the number.

How to change it to be a predefined array like:

```
$numbers = array (
    '+41240000000',
    '+41240000003',
    '+41240000007'
);
```

Here is the `changernum.agi` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$|=1;

use Net::Ping;
use Asterisk::AGI;


$AGI = new Asterisk::AGI;

my %input = $AGI->ReadParse();

my ($number, $idv) = @ARGV;
$number="+4124".int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10));


***I think I need something here***

$AGI->exec("SET numafficher=$number");
$AGI->verbose( "******* / **** / > Numero: $number < ======== ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rand EXPR](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) generates a random number between `0` and `EXPR`. You can use this behavior to get a random element of an array:

```
my @predefined = (
    '+41240000000',
    '+41240000003',
    '+41240000007'
);
my $number = $predefined[rand(@predefined)];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, should I replace these 2 lines:
my ($number, $idv) = @ARGV;
$number="+4124".int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10)).int(rand(10));

Comment: Yes. I am not sure about `$idv` though. It doesn't seem to be used.